# Using telnetlib - backslash is doubled in 'tn.write' (but not in 'print') - how to send single backslash in my write string

Tags: python, backslash, telnetlib

I'm trying to telnet a string to a server using Python 2.7 (in Windows).

The application requires backslashes in the string like this: 'E\myMacro\\', so it needs a single backslash within it, and ends with double backslash.

I have been successful using the cmd module but have failed in Python 2.7.

Here's the code:

```
import telnetlib
host = "myHost"
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
tn.set_debuglevel(100)
data = tn.read_until("server")

myLine = r'E\myMacro'+'\\\\'

tn.write(myLine)
tn.close()

print myLine
```

This is my output:

```
Telnet(myHost,23): recv 'Welcome to the server'
Telnet(myHost,23): send 'E\\myMacro\\\\'
E\myMacro\\
```

I've tried every permutation I can think of to create the string but without success.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? Why is there a difference between tn.write and print?

Comment: Cannot test the telnet communication, but I have noticed that `r'E\\myMacro'` is a raw string, i.e. there should be only one backslash in that string.

Comment: What is weird is the message `Telnet(myHost,23): send 'E\\myMacro\\\\'`. Because `'\\\\'` is the same as `r'\\'` and only contains 2 backslashes. And the first part `r'E\\myMacro'` also contains 2 backslashes because of the initial `r`.

Comment: Thank you both! I realise I have made a typo here, so I've edited the post. As you've pointed out the line should have read myLine = r'E\myMacro'+'\\\\'. And as if that wasn't enough, I also misled you on the output - print gives E\myMacro\\ (also amended above)

Comment: try Telnet(myHost,23): send 'E\\myMacro\/\'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem, in the end it proved to be a very simple fix:

```
import telnetlib
host = "myHost"
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
myLine = 'E\myMacro'
tn.write(myLine+'\\\\\r\n')
tn.write("exit\n")
```